# Can't trap SIGTERM with sigaction function

Tags: c, signals, sigterm

I compiled the program. Starting it and waiting. I open the other terminal, and kill the any running program with command "kill pid" or "kill -15 pid" or "kill -SIGTERM pid" (replace PID with the actual process ID). The killed program is exit, but can't trap SIGTERM to print "done.".

I copy code here: https://airtower.wordpress.com/2010/06/16/catch-sigterm-exit-gracefully/.

Can I help you? I am appreciated all answers.

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

volatile sig_atomic_t done = 0;

void term(int signum)
{
    done = 1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct sigaction action;
    memset(&action, 0, sizeof(struct sigaction));
    action.sa_handler = term;
    sigaction(SIGTERM, &action, NULL);

    int loop = 0;
    while (!done)
    {
        int t = sleep(3);
        /* sleep returns the number of seconds left if
         * interrupted */
        while (t > 0)
        {
            printf("Loop run was interrupted with %d "
                "sec to go, finishing...\n", t);
            t = sleep(t);
        }
        printf("Finished loop run %d.\n", loop++);
    }

    printf("done.\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code is working fine?

Comment: Yes, I run it normally.

Comment: I am reading and following here: https://airtower.wordpress.com/2010/06/16/catch-sigterm-exit-gracefully. But can't trap SIGTERM to print "done.".

Comment: Your program is catching the `SIGTERM` perfectly. I am not clear what your need.

Comment: Running your program in one terminal as `./a.out`. Then open the other terminal then get the process id of that `./a.out`. Then kill `PID`. This is what I am doing.

Comment: It is working fine on linux, where are you trying??

Comment: On which platform do you observer this, using which build command, please?

Comment: Additionally, can you show exactly what you do in a way we can reproduce? Something like `./a.out & sleep 2; kill -SIGTERM $!`.

Comment: You are not setting your mask for your handler. You need to use `sigemptyset(...)` and `sigaddset(...)` to register to the signals you want to handle.

Answer (score -1):

You need to setup your signal handler correctly in order to handle signals you want to catch. This is how I do my signal handler:

```
static void handle_signal(int signum); //in header, then implement

//in the source file
struct sigaction myaction;
myaction.sa_handler = handle_signal;
myaction.sa_flags = 0; //or whatever flags you want but do it here so the signals you register see these flags

sigset_t mask;
sigemptyset(&mask);

sigaddset(&mask, SIGTERM);
sigaction(SIGTERM, &myaction, NULL);

myaction.sa_mask = mask;
```

I am able to catch `SIGTERM` as well as all the other signals I register there (to `sigaddset` and `sigaction`).